# What's the best way to handle a quadratic constraint

Tags: constraints, constrained-optimization

What is the best way to handle a constraint of the type $ax_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2=c$ in a gradient descent algorithm?

I would like to solve an optimization problem of the type:
$$ \min J(x_1,..,x_n)$$ 
with this constraint using gradient descent. I tried to think of a way to alter the gradient so that it doesn't affect the constraint, but I didn't manage to do something useful.

---

What I did was that after each gradient descent, I projected (in a more or less correct way...) the result onto the constraint. I got the results I wanted, but I don't think my approach was 100% valid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's a valid way of incorporating constraints into nonlinear programming problems. These types of algorithms are called *reduced gradient* or *gradient projection* methods. The method of that type I'm most familiar with is the *generalized reduced gradient* (GRG) method, and there are other methods out there as well.

Comment: Is there a rule which indicates how should the projection be made? For example, in my case I have 21 variables. I should modify all variables in "the same way" to reach the constraint. I modified only the first variable to reach the desired constraint (in my case, the variables were related to the geometry of a shape, and the first variable had only a sort of homothetical effect...), but I encountered problems where I unsuccessfully tried all sorts of projections but the "good one".

Comment: You normally project onto constraints that are active. It's been a while since I've read up on that, but the literature should specify what types of projection work better.

Comment: Your constraint is an ellipsoid. It shouldn't be very difficult to just find the closest point on the surface from $x_k+\delta x_k$.